# Optimization based on rank and absolute deviation

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I have a problem statement where i am trying to optimize the position of the shipment such that 2 specific objectives are met, Deviation time and inherent ranking

Given: some Shipments, the objective is to sequence them in a way such that the deviation between the actual start - planned start is minimized, while also ensuring that the ranking of shipments is optimized.

Example: 3 shipments which need to be executed at [10 am, 12 noon, 1 PM] , assuming each statement takes 1 hour to be executed, what should be the sequence of execution?

```
Shipments [S1 S2 S3]
Planned ranking [1 2 3]
Planned time [10,12,13]
```

The solver should give me a solution where the ranking and deviation between the planned and actual time should be less

Example Solution
Optimized ranking can be [2 1 3] execute S2 first, then S1 and finally S3
Optimized time can be anywhere between 1 - 24 depending on other constraints.
hence S2 can begin at either 1 and can take values till 22
S1 should begin after S2 and can take matters from S1 end time till 23
and S3 should begin after S2 and S1 and can take values from the End of S1 till 24.

I was able to write down the ranking part where the objective function is Minimizing the rank(Derived froma pre-determined matrix) and binary choice of shipment and position:

'''

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from pulp import *

shipments = {'D1':1, 'D2':2, 'D3':3}
positions = {'P1':1, 'P2':2, 'P3':3}
endtime = {'D1':10, 'D2':15, 'D3':20}

rank={('D1', 'P1'): 2,
('D1', 'P2'): 4,
('D1', 'P3'): 7,
('D2', 'P1'): 3,
('D2', 'P3'): 2,
('D2', 'P2'): 1,
('D3', 'P3'): 1,
('D3', 'P2'): 2,
('D3', 'P1'): 3}

shipments_labels = sorted(shipments.keys())
positions_labels = sorted(positions.keys())

BIG_M = 9999.9 

# Binary to hold shipment assigned to position    
x = LpVariable.dicts("x", (shipments_labels,positions_labels), 0, 1, LpInteger)
y = LpVariable.dicts("y", (shipments_labels,positions_labels), 1, 24, LpInteger) # to hold the time starting for shipment
y_diff = LpVariable.dicts("y_diff", (shipments_labels),  cat='Real') # to hold absolute deviations

print(x)
print(y)
print(y_diff)
print(rank[('D1', 'P1')])


prob = LpProblem("ranking", LpMinimize)

prob += (lpSum([(rank[(i,j)]**2 -1) * x[i][j] for i in shipments_labels for j in positions_labels]), 
                'Total_Cost') # Objective Function


# #every shipment should be assigned a position
for i in shipments_labels:
    prob += (lpSum([x[i][j] for j in positions_labels])==1) 

# #every position only 1 shipment
for i in positions_labels:
    prob += (lpSum([x[j][i] for j in shipments_labels])==1) 


prob.solve()

for v in prob.variables():
    print(v)
    print(v.varValue)
```

'''

However, I am confused about how to code the deviation logic into the objective. I created the variables yij to hold the interger value of the allocated time and y_diff to hold the absolute deviation. Since deviation can be both positive and negative, it can be penalized differently.

[1- Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORF56.jpg)

[2- Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLtf6.jpg)

[3- Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbeoV.jpg)

Comment: Your problem statement is very unclear.  What is the "position" of a shipment?  What is the "inherent ranking" of a shipment?  What does it mean to have a high "ranking" number?  How do Ranking and Position relate to the times?  In your example, why shouldn't the shipments 1, 2, and 3 just ship at their planned times if the shipments only take an hour?  Suggest you thoroughly revise the problem statement, example, and maybe provide a more detailed example that clarifies these concepts...

Comment: @AirSquid, I have compiled the problem statement in images attached